# How do I display a variable in a UI Text component?

Tags: unity, c#, ui-design

How can I display a variable (say an integer variable) in Unity's UI text?
The variable may be a public variable from another script.

Can anyone please help me do it (step by step)?

Comment: It sounds like you should work your way through some beginners' tutorials. Displaying a value in UI - like a score counter, timer, or health value - is a very common task that's covered extensively in existing resources. If you run into a particular problem following these tutorials, that's the kind of thing more personalized channels like our Q&A site can help with.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a script that will show the value `myIntValue`, and only ever changes the value on screen when the value changes. Parts of this script will be integrated into whatever script is modifying your integer value. You'll then have a UI component somewhere else that has a `Text` component on it. In the Unity editor, you'd drag the `Text` component onto this script in the inspector. This will assign the `Text` component to the `textComponent` variable in the below script, which will then get updated when the your value changes.

```
public class DisplayValue : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text textComponent;

    private int myIntValue;
    public int MyIntValue
    {
        get { return myIntValue; }
        set
        {
            if(myIntValue != value)
            {
                //Here we're only updating the text shown on screen when the value is changed
                myIntValue = value;
                UpdateText(myIntValue);
            }
        }
    }

    void Awake () {
        //If text hasn't been assigned, disable ourselves
        if (textComponent == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("You must assign a text component!");
            this.enabled = false;
            return;
        }
        UpdateText(myIntValue);
    }

    void UpdateText (int value) {
        //Update the text shown in the text component by setting the `text` variable
        textComponent.text = "Value is: " + value;
    }
}
```

Further, you can see a simpler version of this in the Unity tutorials on [UI Text components](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-text?playlist=17111)

Answer (score 0):

While the other answer explains how you can get your value to a text component, here is a way you can format the string. Instead of using something like

```
textComponent.text = "Value is: " + value;
```

as displayed in the other answer, you can use an [interpolated string, using the `$`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), like such

```
textComponent.text = $"Value is: {value}";
```

Here is a bigger example:

```
int val;

void Start()
{
   val = findObjectOfType<yourScriptName>().VariableName;
}

string name = "John";
string result = $"{name} is {val} years Old";
```